# How to programmatically "follow" a Twitter feed in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I want to add code to my iOS app which prompts users to "follow" my app's Twitter feed after they use the program X number of times. However I want to keep it as simple as possible for the user. What are the best practices for programmatically "follow" a Twitter feed? Right now, I have a link to my Twitter feed in the "Help" screen, but I want to make it more visible to the user and try to get more followers.

EDIT: To clarify, I already know how to pop up a UIAlert after the user opens the app 1 times. I am interested in friction-free ways to get the user to "follow" my twitter feed. If possible, I'd like it so that users don't actually have to enter their username & password if they are already logged into Twitter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MGTwitterEngine implements this method

```
- (NSString *)enableUpdatesFor:(NSString *)username; // friendships/create (follow username)
```

I do not use Twitter, but I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use enableUpdatesFor:username without using xAuth with Twitter?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a count of how many times `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is fired by storing a count in NSUserDefaults. If the count (after increment) is a certain limit, then show a UIAlertView that sends them to your twitter page (or alternatively, uses MGTwitterEngine to log-in and follow you).

Comment: didFinishLaunching may not be the most appropriate place, since when a backgrounded application on iOS4+ is restored from the background that method is not called. A better method to put a hook into might be applicationDidBecomeActive:.

Comment: Not really, I wouldn't want the 'count' of my launches to be related to how often the app moves to the foreground (I switch between applications hundreds of times a day). `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is the best place.

Comment: I think the OP's statement "after they use the program X number of times" fits fine with the idea of applicationDidBecomeActive:. Switching to the app again sounds like a single use of the program to me.

Comment: Alternatively, a time-based count might be better. You get X days of actually using the software (i.e. X days where the app was launched at least once that day).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to MGTwitterEngine. However, so you know, I am less interested in how to find out how to launch a UIAlert after the app launches X times (that I can already do) as much as with how to do the actual "following."

Comment: You won't be able to get them to follow you without a username or password. Simple. Learn how to communicate with twitter's RESTful API or use MGTwitterEngine.